# Date conversion query

Tags: datetime, r

I've come into possession of hundreds of ascii data files where the date and time are separate columns like so:

```
date     time
1-Jan-08  23:05
```

I need to convert this to a usable R Date object, subtract 8 hours (timezone conversion from UTC to Pacific) and then turn it into unix time. I need to do this since the data are collected every evening (from 5pm through 2am the following morning). So if I were to use regular date/time format it would confound days (day1 spans two days when in fact it was just one evening of data collection). I'd like to consider each day's events separately.

Using unixtime will allow me to calculate time differences in events that occur each day (I will probably retain a date field in addition to the unix time). Can someone suggest an efficient way to do this?

Here is some data to use (this is in UTC)

```
dummy=data.frame(date="1-Jan-08",time="23:05")
```

Answer (score 4):

Paste them together (which works vectorised) and then parse, e.g.

```
  datetime <- paste(dummy$date, dummy$time)
  parsed <- strptime(datetime, "%d-%b-%y %H:%M")
```

which you can also assign as columns in the data frame.

*Edit:* `strptime()` has an optional `tz=""` argument you can use.

Comment: The date is still in UTC. When I subtract hours, it automatically assigns a time zone which isn't correct. How do I tell it that it is in UTC to begin with and needs to be converted to PST before turning it into a unix timestamp?

Comment: add tz = "GMT" and then do the subtraction - strptime will use the tz used by your system if not specified, and I've always found it simplest to do it this way

Comment: Got that part. In terms of timezone conversion, can I just do parsed=parsed - 5*60*60 (to subtract 5 hours for central time)? Are there other time zone conversion errors I am overlooking? Is there a more direct way to go from GMT to CDT or PST?